# Most elegant way to clip a line?

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, clipping

I have a Rectangle2D and a Line2D. I want to "clip" the line so that only the part of the line which is within the rectangle remains. If none of the line is within the rectangle I want the line to be set to (0,0,0,0). Basically something along the lines of a

```
Rectangle2D.intersect(Line2D src, Line2D dest)
```

or something similar.

Is there a way to do this with the java.awt.geom API? Or an elegant way to code it "by hand"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up doing it myself.

For those intereseted, I ended up solving it by turning the line into a rectangle (with getBounds), then using `Rectangle.intersect(clipRect,lineRect,intersectLineRect)` to create the intersection, then turning the intersection back into a line.

Comment: This part could use a little more detail: "turning the intersection back into a line." The endpoints of the clipped line can lie on the edges of the intersection rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

The source code for [`Rectangle2D.intersectLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersects-double-double-double-double-) might be helpful:

```
public boolean intersectsLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    int out1, out2;
    if ((out2 = outcode(x2, y2)) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    while ((out1 = outcode(x1, y1)) != 0) {
        if ((out1 & out2) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((out1 & (OUT_LEFT | OUT_RIGHT)) != 0) {
            double x = getX();
            if ((out1 & OUT_RIGHT) != 0) {
                x += getWidth();
            }
            y1 = y1 + (x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
            x1 = x;
        } else {
            double y = getY();
            if ((out1 & OUT_BOTTOM) != 0) {
                y += getHeight();
            }
            x1 = x1 + (y - y1) * (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);
            y1 = y;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

where `outcode()` is defined as:

```
public int outcode(double x, double y) {
    int out = 0;
    if (this.width <= 0) {
        out |= OUT_LEFT | OUT_RIGHT;
    } else if (x < this.x) {
        out |= OUT_LEFT;
    } else if (x > this.x + this.width) {
        out |= OUT_RIGHT;
    }
    if (this.height <= 0) {
        out |= OUT_TOP | OUT_BOTTOM;
    } else if (y < this.y) {
        out |= OUT_TOP;
    } else if (y > this.y + this.height) {
        out |= OUT_BOTTOM;
    }
    return out;
}
```

(from [OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.java))

It shouldn't be extremely difficult to change this to clip instead of returning true or false.

Comment: While parts of this boolean test are similar to the Cohen–Sutherland algorithm, I found it easier to start from pseudocode for the algorithm than adapting the AWT `intersectsLine()` boolean test. But I think the `outcode()` helper function can be pretty much used as is.

Answer (score 1):

There's no pretty way to do it with AWT.  Your best bet is something like the [Cohen-Sutherland algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen-Sutherland).  [Here's a link with example Java code](http://shamimkhaliq.50megs.com/Java/lineclipper.htm) (lern2indent, amirite?) to show you how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The usual thing to do is restrict the clipping region in the graphics context with `Graphics2D.clip`. You might want to call `Graphics.create` so that you do not interfere with the original context.

```
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gOrig.create();
try {
    g.clip(clip);
    ...
} finally {
    g.dispose();
}
```

Comment: It's kind of what java.awt.geom is designed for.

Comment: Otherwise, well you have the raw data to do the math by yourself.